# How to make function loop on its own separate line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written for a coding problem assigned to me essentially there is a scratch and win ticket and I have to figure out what prizes I could win. I will be given 10 inputs and each output after running through should be on its own line. However Every time I run the code with 10 inputs all of the inputs just appear on one line.

How do I make sure that each output appears on its own line?

Although to be noted my code does output the correct answer its just the formatting that is troubling I want each answer to be on its own line instead of just being on one line.

```
from collections import Counter


def Winner(L):
    zz = Counter(L)
    if zz["63"] == 9:
        print("No Prizes Possible")
    elif zz["63"] == 0:
        for T in zz:
            if zz[T] >= 3:
                print("$" + T, end=" ")
    else:
        for V in zz:
            KK = zz[V] + zz["63"]
            if KK >= 3:
                if V != "63":
                    print("$" + V, end=" ")

for d in range(10):
    z = [input() for i in range(9)]
    yy = []
    for g in z:
        if g == "?":
            yy.append(ord(g))
        else:
            yy.append(g.replace("$", ""))

    yy = [int(i) for i in yy]
    yy.sort()
    yy = [str(i) for i in yy]
    Winner(yy)
```

Here is a sample input of what I mean:

```
$10
$100
?
$10
$1
$50
$50
$1000
$1
```

essentially having 10 inputs like these.

Comment: Why do you pass `end=" "` to print? This suppresses the newlines that `print` inserts by default

Comment: Because Each input might have more then 1 possible prize so that's why I needed all the possible prizes in one line.

Comment: In that case, simply add an empty `print()` call directly after the `for` loops. This will insert a newline after the line of prizes.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `\n` (the newline character) at the end of your string, you will add a newline after each time your program prints. For example, you could have this loop which would print "hello world" 10 times, each on its own separate line.

```py
for i in range (10):
     print('hello world', '\n')
```

Or more conveniently, you can get rid of the `end = " "`, and Python will automatically add a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `end=" "` in your `print` function.

Just leave it as `print("$" + T)` and `print("$" + V)` so it appends newline by default.